# Who is this guy helping Harry Osborn?

Tags: character, the-amazing-spider-man-2

At the end of the movie [The Amazing Spider-Man 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFQxP.jpg), a guy meets Harry Osborn in the penitentiary and talks to Harry about unleashing villains like Rhino.

[image: Some Guy]

Who's this guy helping Harry? Is he Harry's father?

Comment: I thought Harry's father died.

Comment: related http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/who-is-the-man-in-the-credit-scene-in-the-amazing-spider-man

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - It's a comic book story. No one stays dead. No one! Except *maybe* Uncle Ben.

Comment: that man is Michael Massee it was the man in the shadows in amazing spiderman 1 and the gentleman in number 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That man is [Gustav Fiers](http://amazingspiderman.wikia.com/wiki/Gustav_Fiers), also known as the "Man in the Shadows". You may remember him from the first film:

[image]

Here he visited Curt Connors to ask whether he had told Peter the truth about his father. When Curt tells him to leave Peter alone, he disappears.

In that film, he is credited as the Man in the Shadows. In Amazing Spiderman 2 he is finally given a name, being credited as "Gustav Fiers (The Gentleman)".

A quick search for Gustav Fiers reveals:

> During Adam-Troy Castro's Sinister Six trilogy of Spider-Man novels, a new Sinister Six - consisting of Doctor Octopus, the Vulture, Electro, Mysterio, the Chameleon, and an original character called Pity - are formed by Gustav Fiers, a notorious criminal known as the Gentleman, who wishes to kill Peter Parker in revenge for the actions of his parents in thwarting some of the Gentleman's schemes in the 1960s.

It appears likely therefore that he will be some sort of "super villain" in the remaining movie(s).